# What is Catalyst Optimizer in Apache Spark (SQL)?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know more about Catalyst Optimizer in Apache PySpark (SQL).Is it possible to use Catalyst Optimizer in pyspark dataframe.

Comment: Try and google, e.g. this comes up: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781786463708/3/ch03lvl1sec18/catalyst-optimizer-refresh

Answer (score 3):

Dataframes created using SQL can leverage the Spark Catalyst framework.
Using pyspark(assuming variable `spark` is bound to `SparkSession`), we could invoke a SQL like

```
spark.sql(<sql>)
```

This would be analyzed, optimized and physical plans created by Catalyst framework.

If the Dataframe is hand-constructed like `spark.table<>.sort(<col>)`, Spark catalyst does not come into play.
If we want to leverage Catalyst framework for a dataframe which is not a table backed by a metastore, we could register it as a temp table, and use SQL to fire queries.

Answer (score 2):

Catalyst Optimizer is Spark's internal SQL engine.  Spark Dataframe's use the Catalyst Optimizer under the hood to build a query plan to best decide how the code should be executed across the cluster to scale performance, etc.  Instead of rambling/writing an essay on specifics here are some great reads. Enjoy!

https://databricks.com/glossary/catalyst-optimizer